# Should code be refactored to be more unit testable or should a framework like PowerMock be used?

Tags: unit-testing, programming-practices, testing, code-quality, static-methods

Assume there's some code that's already in production that needs some unit testing. Generally speaking, would you want to refactor this code that's already in production by adding things like adding wrappers, or add in a testing framework like PowerMock? I've heard it's bad practice to use powermock, but it seems unreasonable to modify code in production just for the sake of testing it.

Comment: -1 for assuming everyone knows you are talking of Java.

Comment: @DocBrown Does it matter if it's java or not?

Comment: @Goldname It matters a bit. In something like Python, dynamically patching the dependencies is pretty much the preferred way of unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the risk-benefit analysis of each approach.

- *Why* does this code "need" some unit testing? What actual benefit is this going to give?
- How much risk is it to refactor it to be unit testable in a "standard" fashion?
- How much risk is it to use PowerMock?

We can't answer any of those for you, because we don't know your code.

Personally, even when working with the cruftiest codebases, I have found very few that cannot be incrementally refactored to introduce unit tests - I strongly recommend [*Working Effectively with Legacy Code*](https://www.informit.com/store/working-effectively-with-legacy-code-9780131177055) as a toolbox of techniques for getting unit tests into an existing codebase.